# Start Terminator via shell script in broadcast mode

Tags: gnome, bash, terminator

I currently use a small script to start a terminator window as a background process which has multiple splits specified with a layout.

```
terminator --layout=My_layout &
```

I want to execute a command to connect to a remote server in all the splits.

When I use this,

```
terminator --layout=My_layout -x command_to_connect arg1 arg2 &
```

only the 1st window is connected.

How do I broadcast the message to all the windows from my script?

I have a key binding specified for broadcast. How do I use that when starting a new window?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must change the terminator config file and add "dbus = True" then you can open a new terminator windows like `terminator -e "ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" --new-tab`